# Android : Stop Sync to Gmail, allow all rest apps to sync

Tags: android, calendar, gmail, synchronization

Is there any method so that I can stop syncing to gmail.
I want that only my Google Calendar, contacts and everything else to be synced but except Gmail.
Gmail uses a lot of phone's internal memory, and my phone is only left with 25MB free internal memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into Settings -> Accounts and Sync -> select your google account and uncheck the gmail sync option.

That should keep everything else you wanted synced but stop gmail coming down.

Comment: Hi, there is no option to uncheck. When I went there an exclamatory mark was there in front of gmail, and its written below that Touch to sync. Now I have touched it, and its syncing. The animation is moving.